# Is there any PHP.ini setting for curl status code 415?

Tags: php, curl

I have tried to call API for send image file using `CURL` .But I am getting below error:

```
"statusCode":415,
"error":"Unsupported Media Type"
```

Please help me.

I have attached code here:

```
$filename = "screenshot.jpg";
$handle = fopen($filename, "r");
$xml = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
fclose($handle);
 $jwt_token = "xxx";
$authorization = "Authorization:".$jwt_token;
$url = "https://prod0-commerce-api.sprinklr.com/media_upload";
$headers = array(             
                            "Content-Type: image/jpg]",
                            "Cache-Control: no-cache", 
                            "Pragma: no-cache", 
                            $authorization
                            ); 
$postdata = array('fileName' => '@'.$filename,
            'type' => 'IMAGE'); //<-------------

        $soap_do = curl_init(); 
        curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_URL,            $url);   
        //curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 60); 
        //curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,        60); 
        curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
        curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);  
        //curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false); 
        curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_POST,           true ); 
        curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,     $postdata); //<----------- 
        curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,     $headers); 

        $result = curl_exec($soap_do);
        // Check for errors and display the error message
        curl_close($soap_do);
        $httpcode = curl_getinfo($soap_do, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        echo $httpcode;
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($result);
if($errno = curl_errno($soap_do)) {
    $error_message = curl_strerror($errno);
    echo "cURL error ({$errno}):\n {$error_message}";
}
echo "string";exit();
        print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in this block:

```
$postdata = array('fileName' => '@'.$filename,
                  'type' => 'IMAGE'); //<-------------
```

The value of `type` should be a valid [MIME type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_type) (aka "media type" or "content type").

A MIME type is an identifier composed of two parts (the type and the subtype) joined by slash (`/`).

The type identifies the category of content (text, image, audio, video, application etc). The subtype identifies more accurate the content inside the category.

For images, the type is `image` and there are several subtypes: `gif`, `jpeg`, `png` etc.

A correct MIME type for an image file looks like `image/jpeg` or `image/png` and not just `IMAGE`. This is why the server rejects your query.

The PHP function [`getimagesize()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php) can be used to find the MIME type of a image stored in a file.

Your code should be like this:

```
$imgInfo = getimagesize($filename);
$postdata = array('fileName' => '@'.$filename,
                  'type' => $imgInfo['mime']);
```

And no, there is no setting in `php.ini` that writes correct code for you.

Comment: API  allow only 3 types value IMAGE,VIDEO,FILES

Answer (score 1):

> I have solved using this solution

```
<?php

$file = "http://localhost/xxx/screenshot.jpg";
$boundary = md5(time());
$eol = "\r\n"; 
$params  = "----".$boundary.$eol
    . "Content-Disposition: form-data;name=\"type\"".$eol
    . $eol
    . "IMAGE"
    . $eol
    . "----".$boundary.$eol
    . "Content-Disposition: form-data;name=\"file\"; filename=\"screenshot.jpg\"".$eol
    . '"Content-Type: image/jpeg\"'.$eol
    . $eol
    . file_get_contents($file) .$eol
    . "----".$boundary."--";

$jwt_token = "xxxx";
$authorization = "Authorization:".$jwt_token;

$first_newline      = strpos($params, $eol);
$multipart_boundary = substr($params, 2, $first_newline - 2);
$request_headers    = array();
$request_headers[]  = $authorization;
$request_headers[]  = 'Accept: application/json';
$request_headers[]  = 'Content-Length: ' . strlen($params);
$request_headers[]  = 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary='. $multipart_boundary;

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'xxx');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $request_headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
 $result = curl_exec($ch);
 $info = curl_getinfo($ch);


curl_close($ch);
  echo "<pre>";
print_r($result);

exit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Most of time a error 415 appears when you don't set properly  the **Content-Type.** Maybe you can put Content-Type:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: image/jpg"));
```

Comment: I have set 
"Content-type: application/json;charset=\"utf-8\"",

Comment: if i set as u suggest i got this error "Invalid content-type header "

Comment: Yep, you copied-past my post, i mean : "Content-Type: image/jpg"

Comment: I don't know if you runed the same code, wrong syntax "Content-Type: image/jpg]" => "Content-Type: image/jpg"

Comment: Which API do you use? Are you sure, you can or authorize to post image?

Comment: I am using sprinklr API .it is working fine POSTMAN rest client